# how to select only some part of data from a table column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have created a SQL SERVER script . first of all please check the script

```
SELECT
  W.RequesterName + ' ' + +'on ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), W.Requested, 111) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), W.Requested, 108) + ' ' + (CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, W.Requested) > 12 THEN 'PM'
    ELSE 'AM'
  END) AS 'Request Detail',
  W.TakenByName,
  W.Reason,
  CONVERT(varchar(20), W.TargetDate, 111) + '   (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CAST(W.TargetHours AS float)) + ')' + ' hr' AS targetWorkDetails,
  W.PriorityDesc + '/' + W.TypeDesc AS priorityDesc,
  W.SupervisorName,
  W.ShopID,
  W.RepairCenterName,
  W.RequesterPhone,
  A.Location3Name,
  A.ParentLocation,
  A.ParentLocationAll,
  W.AssetName,
  W.AssetName + '(' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),w.AssetID,101) + ')' AS AssetDetails

FROM WO W
INNER JOIN AssetHierarchy A
  ON W.AssetPK = A.AssetPK
WHERE w.WOPK = 10144 --INNER JOIN AssetHierarchy ON WO.AssetPK=AssetHierarchy.AssetPK
```

and now please check my output

[image]

now please check the highlighted attribute which is 'ParentLocationAll' . my task is to get the ParentLocationAll data before 
 tag start . for example here in ParentLocationAll column we have value 'Wood Buffalo
Main Building' i would like to take only 'Wood Buffalo' . i would like to give one more example : suppose we have value 'calgery
abcd' in 'ParentLocationAll' column . then i have to take only 'calgery' instead of whole value . 
i have tried hard but couldn't solve the issue . please help me with some good
suggestion .thanks in advance .

Comment: In order to answer this, we would need specific, explicit ways to know what the rules are of how you discern what to split out rather than simple examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `PATINDEX` with `LEFT` might work here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Wood Buffalo<br>Main Building' AS ParentLocationAll
)

SELECT
    LEFT(ParentLocationAll d, PATINDEX('%<%>%', ParentLocationAll) - 1) AS ParentLocation
FROM yourTable;

Wood Buffalo  <-- output
```

### Demo

Whether this would work in all cases would depend on your data.  For example, if your parent location column had random `<` or `>` symbols, appearing not in the context of an HTML tag, then my solution could fail.

Comment: in my case the HTML tag will always come for ParentLocationAll column .@Tim

Answer (score 1):

Strictly based on the input data provided below code snippet would do the job -

```
create table #table (ParentLocationAll nvarchar(1000))
insert into #table (ParentLocationAll) select 'Wood Buffalo Main Building'
insert into #table (ParentLocationAll) select 'calgery abcd'
select 
       case when len(ParentLocationAll) - len(replace(ParentLocationAll, ' ', '')) = 1 
       then LEFT(ParentLocationAll, charindex(' ', ParentLocationAll) - 1) 
       else SubString(ParentLocationAll, 1, CharIndex(' ', ParentLocationAll, CharIndex(' ', ParentLocationAll) + 1)) end as ParentLocationAll
from #table
```

So, here the code is just checking the number of spaces(' ') in your string and if the count is 1 then the it would extract the string till it finds the first space else it would find the second space in your main string and extract the string till then.